# No Reputation awarded for the accepted answer

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I have answered a question on Stack Overflow, but I didn't get any reputation points for the answer after my answer got accepted. I checked the wiki and search this site and cannot figure out why. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806560/can-not-figure-out-how-splaying-works/10807573#10807573) is the link of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By editing it more than ten times, you automatically made your answer Community Wiki (see [revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10807573/revisions#revf5027f0b-21ed-4f5e-a8d3-11e7486a6d6e)). You cannot earn repuation from Community Wiki posts.

See also: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: that is new information for me, i will take care of editing my answer next time to < 10 :)

Comment: @Lucifer Yea, seems counter intuitive to penalize a fully correct answer

Comment: I have just had the same query regarding one of my accepted answers on:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534780/sql-query-to-pick-up-values-on-some-rules/22538791?noredirect=1#comment34321634_22538791)   I haven't edited it more than 5 times, it isn't a hot post and I don't remember ticknig the add to community wiki box!? If I did, I certainly didn't do it on purpose. Perhaps it needs to be renamed or made more prominent?

Comment: @sarin: Your answer is community wiki because the question is. There cannot be a non-wiki answer to a wiki question.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is **[Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)** answer. In this case you do not get any reputation points for that answer.

You can not have any reputation as accepted answer or vote up for a Community Wiki answer